# How to fix: Net Beans Can't Find 3D Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, netbeans

I am creating a program in NetBeans in which the user plays rock paper scissors against a computer opponent.

Rather than randomly choosing Rock Paper or Scissors, the Computer will have different preferences based on the events of the last round - ie losing to Rock makes it more likely to play paper.

I wanted to do this by creating a 3D array with 2D arrays for when the Computer wins and the Computer loses - which they themselves have an Array for Rock, Paper, and Scissors each.

I ran into my problem when trying to use the array later; specifically in using a .length() to get a random variable then pulling the number from that location.

Netbeans just shows the error "can't find symbol" when hovering over it - despite me declaring the array as both Public and Static.

I tried creating a temporary array equal to one of the arrays inside the inner 2D arrays but ran into the same error.

```
public static int[][][] moveArrays = {
    //Turn 1
    {
        {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3},
        {1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3},
        {1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3},
    },
    //Opponent Wins
    {
        //With Rock
        {1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,},
        //With Paper
        {1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3},
        //With Scissors
        {1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3},
    },
    //Opponent Loses
    {
        //To Rock
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3},
        //To Paper
        {1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3},
        //To Scissors
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,},
    }
};

public void turn1()  {
    int rnd = new Random().nextInt(3);
    switch (rnd) {
        case 0:
            //int[] clone = moveArray[0][0];
            int rnd2 = new Random().nextInt(moveArray[0][0].length());
            enemyChoice = moveArray[0][0][rnd2];
            break;
        case 1:
            int rnd2 = new Random().nextInt(moveArray[0][1].length());
            enemyChoice = moveArray[0][1][rnd2];
            break;
        case 2:
            int rnd2 = new Random().nextInt(moveArray[0][2].length());
            enemyChoice = moveArray[0][2][rnd2];
            break;
    }
}
```

The error "Can't find Symbol" occurs every time moveArray is used.

Comment: Your array is called `moveArrays`, not `moveArray`.

Answer (score 1):

> The error "Can't find Symbol" occurs every time moveArray is used.

Correct. You have declared the array as `moveArrays`, not `moveArray`. Furthermore, arrays have a `.length` variable, not a `.length()` method. "Can't find symbol" means that you either made a typo, and/or haven't defined the reference that you are trying to use.